# User Authentication And Text Parsing in Python

Tags: python, http, authentication, urllib2

Well I am working on a multistage program...
I am having trouble getting the first stage done..
What I want to do is log on to Twitter.com, and then read all the direct messages on the user's page.

Eventually I am going to be reading all the direct messages looking for certain thing, but that shouldn't be hard.

This is my code so far

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import httplib
import sys

userName = "notmyusername"
password  = "notmypassword"
URL = "http://twitter.com/#inbox"

password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_mgr.add_password(None, "http://twitter.com/", userName, password)
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
pageshit = urllib2.urlopen(URL, "80").readlines()
print pageshit
```

So a little insight and and help on what I am doing wrong would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Twitter does not use HTTP Basic Authentication to authenticate its users. It would be better, in this case, to use the Twitter API.

A tutorial for using Python with the Twitter API is here: [`http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorial/Get_Started_With_the_Twitter_API`](http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorial/Get_Started_With_the_Twitter_API()

Answer (score 3):

The regular web interface of Twitter does not use basic authentication, so requesting pages from the web interface using this method won't work.

According to [the Twitter API docs](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-direct_messages), you can retrieve private messages by fetching this URL:

```
http://twitter.com/direct_messages.format
```

Format can be xml, json, rss or atom. This URL does accept basic authentication.

Also, your code does not use the `handler` object that it builds at all.

Here is a working example that corrects both problems. It fetches private messages in json format:

```
import urllib2

username = "USERNAME"
password  = "PASSWORD"
URL = "http://twitter.com/direct_messages.json"

password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_mgr.add_password(None, "http://twitter.com/", username, password)
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
try:
  file_obj = opener.open(URL)
  messages = file_obj.read()
  print messages
except IOError, e:
  print "Error: ", e
```

Comment: Okay i saved it in xml format.. I have the ID of the persons messages I am looking for. In python how can read the line after the ID?

Comment: You need to use an XML parser like `xml.dom`. If you need help with this, I suggest you edit your question and add more details, or open a new question.